# Mean value of 2 dataframes with same dimensions in python

Tags: python, pandas

I imported two csv files in python using read_csv. So now I have 2 dataframes with dimensions 40x300. What I want to do is create a new csv file with dimensions 40x300, where each cell will have the mean value calculated using the values of the respective position in the other two csv files. For example, if the cell with position 1x2 in the first dataframe is 10 and the cell with the same position in the second dataframe is 20, I want a third dataframe with dimensions 40x300 which has the value of 15 in position 1x2. I tried

```
   frame1.add(frame2)
```

but this created a new dataframe with dimensions 40x600. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do your dataframes have the same index and columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Panda is index and column sensitive , when you adding them up, you always need to make sure the two df have the same index and column

```
frame2.index=frame1.index
frame2.columns=frame1.columns
frame1.add(frame2)/2
```

After change the index and columns `concat`will work as well

```
pd.concat([frame1,frame2]).mean(level=0)
```